# Find articles or modules in remote server

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have my website done in Joomla in local and it work fine.

I moved my website to a remote server and now I have links and other things that do not work.

I connect by ssh to my server but I cannot find my custom articles (without category) or my personalize HTML modules.

Where can I find this on my server?

Comment: Your articles should be in the database (table #__content), and if you mean 'custom HTML' module, then the information is in the db too (table #__modules).

Comment: I hope you copied the database as well !

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you didn't move the site over properly. The easiest way to move a site is to use Akeeba - https://www.akeebabackup.com/.